# Blender crashes when i try to render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I try to render it just crashes, I mean, I did a very simple model (a low-poly well)but when I hit render, it just crashes my entire computer. Everything goes dark and my monitor turns off.
I have 16 GB of ram, an intel core i3 9100f, and an RX 570 with 4GB of ram. It just only happens with this render, I did a donut a couple of days ago and everything was fine.

PD: I'm using Cycles renderer.

Comment: Also try to add a screenshot of what your working with next time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bug or something that you haven't noticed.
Try copying all the objects that your working on to a new blend file.